# Como testar uma aplicação sem ter registro?

Tags: ios, xcode, app, apple

Sou desenvolvedor da Apple registrado (mas não pago ), como posso testar minha aplicação no meu iPhone? Ele dá erro quando peço para abrir no iPhone. Estou tentando no IOS 9 com Xcode 7.
Quando tentei ele deu problema, agora o iphone diz que não posso abrir pois o desenvolvedor nao é certificado .... Como mudo isso nas configurações ?

Comment: Veja [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Comment: @JéfersonBueno o SOpt foi criado exatamente pela ideia de que nem todos nós sabemos inglês, por isso seria interessante você elaborar sua resposta em português.

Comment: Brother, no momento eu não posso escrever uma resposta. Eu estou tentando ajudar o AP a resolver o problema. E convenhamos que não tem nada de muito difícil para ler no link que eu mandei, até porque é bem provável que ele use o próprio `XCode` em inglês, inclusive a documentação de praticamente TODAS as linguagens estão em inglês, o mínimo que for nós precisamos saber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você baixar o Xcode 7 Beta ele já disponibiliza a opção de testar a aplicação sem a necessidade de pagar uma licensa de 99$, e uma dica,  use `Testflight`, com ele você pode enviar o seu app para seus amigos testarem e te darem feedback.

Tudo que eu fiz para poder testar minha aplicação no meu celular foi:

1° Instalar Xcode 7 Beta.

2° Abrir preferences -> Account clicar no botão a esquerda  vai abrir um pop up Logue com seu App ID.

3° Plug seu iphone no seu macbook, confirme no seu telefone para confiar no seu macbook, va no xcode, na lista de builds em vez de ficar Device vai aparecer o nome do seu aparelho.

4° vai aparecer uma mensagem chamada "Fix Issue" se o seu nome não estiver selecionado como team.

5° Compile  e não esqueça de deixar o Iphone desbloqueado.

Não sei se tem muito haver mas testei em um macbook usando Yosemite.

Comment: Quando tentei ele deu problema, agora o iphone di que não posso abrir pois o desenvolvedor nao é certificado .... Como mudo isso nas configurações ?

Answer (score 2):

Augusto , para resolver o problema do desenvolvedor não certificado faça o seguinte
Vá em  Ajustes -> Geral -> Perfil em "Aplicativo do Desenvolvedor", de permissão para o id da apple

Comment: vlw Fabio deu certo.